# How to have my bitcoin-cli connect to an outside fullnode

Tags: wallet, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I don't want to run a full node in my laptop. I rather want to install bitcoin-cli only and configure it to connect to an external full node. Is that possible?

If so, two questions:

1. where can I get a list of full nodes?
2. where can I record a full node from the above step in my bitcoin-cli

This is just for a quick test of bitcoin-cli. If there is other way to do this without setting up a full node myself, that works as well

Comment: Will you be setting up your own bitcoind node in another computer and you want to connect to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> configure it to connect to an external full node. Is that possible?

Technically yes, but in practice, no. `bitcoin-cli` connects to a `bitcoind` via the RPC interface. This interface is typically not exposed to the internet nor are all IP addresses typically allowed to connect to it (specific IP addresses or CIDR blocks need to be explicitly allowed by the node operator). This connection limitation is because access to the RPC interface allows access to the wallet and can result in potential coin loss. Additionally, you will need to know the RPC username and password in order to connect.

So, in actuality, you probably won't find any `bitcoind`s with open RPC interfaces that you can connect to, and since the interface is authenticated, you probably won't be able to connect to any node. You will need to have explicit permission from the node operator.

Comment: There's no reason not to do this if you aren't using the Core wallet for that particular Core node right? If that's empty it doesn't matter if someone accesses it.